# How to sync your themes for Google Chrome across computers?

Tags: google-chrome

It seems that the bookmarks get synced but my themes do not... I already have ensured that under the settings, the themes checkbox is checked. I referred to this: [Syncing Google Chrome](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=165139). What else need to be done?

Comment: Have you tried to disconnect from your Google account, restart Chrome, and try again?

Answer (score 2):

Do the following on every device using chrome.

1. Disconnect your accounts from chrome. This can be done in "settings" / Sign in options
2. Clear all settings from the beginning of time. 
   "tools" / "clear browser data" / check everything, and select from the beginning of time.
3. re-sync your account.  Choose whatever you want. I like to sync it all...
4. Close chrome once sync is done.
5. Sync in to another device. (again, make sure you follow steps 1-3 on all devices)
6. Try theme changing.

Note that this will [only work if theme](https://superuser.com/a/752370/4377) was installed from the Chrome Web store

Comment: does this work for custom themes or for any theme in general?