# Chrome theme I made myself refuses to sync across computers, how to sync it?

Tags: google-chrome, sync, google-chrome-extensions

I made a Google Chrome theme, and have loaded it into Google Chrome using the Developer tools (Tools → Check "Developer mode"). But the theme won't sync across computers, even after I followed the steps in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/451044/how-to-sync-your-themes-for-google-chrome-across-computers).

I have been able to sync themes I downloaded from the chrome store across devices, why can't I sync this one? Is the solution that I have to somehow upload the theme to the Chrome store, and then download my own theme?
Chrome themers I need your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is the solution that I have to somehow upload the theme to the Chrome store, and then download my own theme

Yes, Chrome will only sync those items available in the Web store. When Chrome sync runs, it fetches all ids from your existing profile, compares them with the new profile & if the item isn't found, initiates an install from the Web store.

Since your theme isn't found on the web store, there's no way to sync & install it

Answer (score 1):

If you use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/theme-creator/akpelnjfckgfiplcikojhomllgombffc?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) app in the Chrome Store you can create/upload a theme, and then an account for the app. You can then save the theme online. On your other devices, you can then log into the app and add the theme to Chrome.